# Thread.sleep on KitKat

Tags: android, multithreading, android-4.4-kitkat

I have a service which I want to start from a WakefullBroadcastReceiver. This service has to enable wi-fi and then to wait for some time, after that time has to disable wi-fi and stop itself.
My service works fine on JellyBean and also works as expected on KitKat when phone is awake. But on KitKat when phone is in deep sleep the WakefullBroadcastReceiver starts the service which hangs at Thread.sleep. Nothing happens after that and the service never stops.

I tried a lot of things instead of Thread.sleep such object.wait, timer or a second WakefullBroadcastReceiver for a second service to disable wi-fi but everything cause my phone to reboot! Also I changed targetSdkVersion to 18 but there is no difference.

My code is:

```
public class Awservice extends IntentService {
    public static final String PREFS = "Prefs";
    private MyReceiver alarm;
    SharedPreferences mSettings;
        public Awservice() {
            super("Awservice");
        }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        alarm = new MyReceiver();
        mSettings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS,0);
        int api = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        boolean manualState = mSettings.getBoolean("PREFS_MANUALON", true);
        String strDur = mSettings.getString("PREFS_DURATION", "").toString();
        Long Duration = Long.parseLong(strDur)*60*1000;
        ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo NetWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        if (manualState==true) {
            if (NetWifi.isConnected()) {
                alarm.SetAlarm(this);
            } else {
                wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);  
                alarm.SetAlarm(this);
                Thread.sleep(Duration);
                wifi.setWifiEnabled(false);   
            }       
        } else {
            wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);  
            Thread.sleep(Duration);
            wifi.setWifiEnabled(false);
        }
        MyReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }
}
```

Please help me to solve this problem. I have run out of ideas.

Comment: well you have the thread sleep for 1 minute + whatever the value of `strDur` is so it is going to hang at that spot until then

Comment: What can I do then to make service to wait some minutes?

Comment: Is your service being destroyed during the sleep? Android call kill services due to low memory or other issues. Couldn't you use something like a pending intent of a minute to shut the wifi back off?

Comment: use a `Timer` and then disable wifi and cancel service when the timer goes off

Comment: @bestdayever No, Android doesn't kill my service. Just system ignores my service which runs in background.

Comment: @tyczj I used a timer but just after activation of wi-fi system hangs and then reboots. I will try with another phone. Maybe is kernel problem because I use a custom kernel.